# Can't use parenthesis in MSQL view WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have a MYSQL view that does not return the correct rows. I am quite sure it comes from the WHERE clause but I can't write it the way I need.

This is what I believe it should be:

```
WHERE (`iu`.`ingredient_status` <> 5 AND `iud`.`doc_complete` = 1 AND `iu`.`used_in_formulas` = 1)
OR    (`iu`.`add_reference` = 1 AND `iu`.`ref_added` = 0)
```

The view was created with Navicat but when I save it, it strips the parenthesis and saves only:

```
WHERE `iu`.`ingredient_status` <> 5 AND `iud`.`doc_complete` = 1 AND `iu`.`used_in_formulas` = 1
OR    `iu`.`add_reference` = 1 AND `iu`.`ref_added` = 0
```

I tried also Adminer, but it does the same. Are you not allowed to use parenthesis in WHERE clauses or am I missing something?

Comment: Either this is Navicat issue or you did something wrongly.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use parenthesis in WHERE clauses - in mysql yes parentheses are fine, can't comment on navicat and it seems unlikely that adminer would do the same..

Comment: The query is identical without parenthesis (if you look at precedence chart of SQL operators you'll understand why). Something else is wrong, your logic perhaps.

Comment: *but when I save it, it strips the parenthesis and saves only* Where and how do you look for this? MySQL, in turn, will add some parenthesis to the fragment shown, till ```where (((`iu`.`ingredient_status` <> 5) and (`iud`.`doc_complete` = 1) and (`iu`.`used_in_formulas` = 1)) or ((`iu`.`add_reference` = 1) and (`iu`.`ref_added` = 0)))```. See `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname;`.

Comment: the AND always has precedence over OR, both commands are exactly the same. Your database strips the parenthesis because they are useless.

Comment: I did not know about precedence. I will think again the logic. Thanks all.